# Using a loop to assign values to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use 2 loops that will assign a value into a 2d array. The goal is that the numbers are either 0 or 16777215. When using the code I have made, everything 300 values that are printed, 16777215 is used. I have replaced both the values in the if and else statement and it has continued. The values should be randomly be chosen between 0 and 16777215. The code I have currently is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] draw = new int[400][300];
    for (int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++) {
        for (int b = 0; i < draw[i].length; i++) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                int x = 16777215; // num for black
                                  // should normally be 0 but for trial purposes, I used 16777215
                draw[i][b] = x;
            } else {
                int x = 16777215; // num for white
                draw[i][b] = x;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < draw[i].length; b++) {
            System.out.println(draw[i][b]);
            //should be a random spread of 0 and 16777215 but 16777215 appears only every 300 lines in the output. 
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: First appears at 289, then at additions of 300(ex 589, 889)

Comment: Num for black and white are the same. Both sides of the if are identical

Comment: OP note both answers are correct, you have numerous (edit: well, I guess just those two) issues in your code.

Comment: Hint: you should also avoid using all those hardcoded values, too. At least define something like `private final static int BLACK = 16...` (but better use an enum with a "custom" int value). And then do `draw[i][b] = BLACK` for example. There is no point in having that x variable here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `for (int b = 0; i < draw[i].length; i++)`

Shouldn't that be `for (int b = 0; b < draw[i].length; b++)` ?

The array is initialized with 0 in every position. That is why you are seeing so many zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner for loop you have incremented the value of i.

I think you should have used variable b in your inner loop.

According to your loop your loop sequence will run as follows

0,0

0,0

0,0 ....

1,0

1,0

If you modify inner loop as follows

```
    for (int b = 0; b < draw[i].length; b++)
```

the sequence will be

0,0

0,1

0,2...

1,0

1,1 and so on

Corrected Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] draw = new int[400][300];
for (int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < draw[i].length; b++) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            int x = 16777215;
            draw[i][b] = x;
        } else {
            int x = 16777215;
            draw[i][b] = x;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < draw.length; i++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < draw[i].length; b++) {
        System.out.println(draw[i][b]); 
    }
}
}
```